# How to group by and then get rows with IDs in the supplied array

Tags: postgresql

My table structure:

```
table_A_id bigint,
group_id bigint,
sub_id bigint
```

I have an external 2D array of bigint. You can think of it as a list of possible sub id's a group must match to be selected.

For example if I had 10 rows in my database as (ordered for readability):

```
table_A_id | group_id | sub_id
---------------------------------
   1            1         1
   2            1         2
   3            1         3
   4            2         1
   5            2         2
   6            2         4
   7            2         5
   8            3         1
   9            3         5
   10           3         6
```

And the 2d array was

```
[
   [1, 4],
   [1, 6]
]
```

Then rows 4,6,8,10 would be selected as the groups they are within have a combined set of ids which contain ALL the items from one of the arrays within the 2d array.

```
Edit--
Rephrase as requested:
Grouping the rows by group_id gives
group 1 with sub_ids [1,2,3]
group 2 with sub_ids [1,2,4,5]
group 3 with sub_ids [1,5,6]
group 2 has both 1 & 4 within it's sub_ids, matching an array in the 2d array, therefore those rows are selected (4,6)
group 3 has both 1 & 6 within it's sub_ids, so those rows are also selected (8 & 10)
group 1 only has a matching sub_id of 1 and not also 4 or 6 so no rows from group 1 are selected
```

So far, I am struggling with a 1d array:

```
DEALLOCATE my_proc;
PREPARE my_proc (bigint[][]) AS
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ufs.group_id, ufs.sub_id
        FROM table_A AS ufs
        GROUP BY ufs.group_id, ufs.sub_id
    ) AS ufs;
    --WHERE ufs.sub_id = ALL($1);

EXECUTE my_proc(array[array[1, 2], array[1,3]]);
```

Comment: I dont see why you select rows 4,6,8,10 could you elaborate

Comment: Sure, I've edited, thanks for looking

Comment: I understand better, but still confused, why there is two group 1 and two group 3? And please can you post what is the result you want, do you want rows, or arrays?

Comment: There can be one group 1 and one group 3 if that makes it easier, as I was just going to put a DISTINCT in later. The requirement is to find out which groups have sub ids that complete any of the supplied arrays in the 2D array. Note: in the example the arrays only had 2 values, but in my app they can have more

Comment: The problem is I still dont understand the question. I could split the array and convert it to a table but dont know if that is what you want

Comment: I want a list of the groups whose sub ids contain all the ids in one or more of the supplied arrays in the 2d array. im sorry, i dont know how else to explain it :(

Comment: do you know the rubber duck? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging You have to explain it like other dont know what you are talking about. Put the example first with one array, then with two. Try to make it simple. Also not put it on comment just improve your question and let me know. And i ask if you could show me your desire output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's rather easy, just use `array_agg` and the contains operator:

```
WITH table1
    ("table_A_id", "group_id", "sub_id")
AS(
    VALUES
      (1, 1, 1),
      (2, 1, 2),
      (3, 1, 3),
      (4, 2, 1),
      (5, 2, 2),
      (6, 2, 4),
      (7, 2, 5),
      (8, 3, 1),
      (9, 3, 5),
      (10, 3, 6)
),
seek(x) AS(
  VALUES 
    (array[1, 2]),
    (array[1,3])
)
SELECT group_id, array_agg(sub_id)
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY group_id
 HAVING array_agg(sub_id) @> ANY(SELECT x FROM seek)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it's not quite there - I dont understand the seek bit. Is it needed? Those values were just examples, and simple represent 
select table_A_id, group_id, sub_id from table1. Thanks

Comment: @user2330270 The CTE part is just an example so the reader can test quickly how it works. The seek bit is just a table with one array per row.